# Spring AOP multiple return type in expression

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-aop

I´m using Spring aop and having just one return type in my expression was just fine

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="webResourceInvocationPointcut"
            expression="execution(public com.es.core.message.ResultOrError com.presentation.resource..*.*(com.es.mus.MUSIn,..))" />
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="webResourceInvocationPointcut" advice-ref="resourceChainOfInterceptors" />
    </aop:config>
```

Here I specify that I want to use aop if the request go to a resource which is `public` the method return type is `com.es.core.message.ResultOrError` and the package and argument in the method are `com.presentation.resource..*.*(com.es.mus.MUSIn,..))`

But now, I would like to allow not only `com.es.core.message.ResultOrError` as a return type but also `java.util.concurrent.Future`

with the wildcard * works, but I need to filter for just this two types. Also adding one after the other it does not work.

I receive this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 89


[3:47] 
execution(public com.es.core.message.ResultOrError java.util.concurrent.Future scala.concurrent.Future com.presentation.resource..*.*(com.es.mus.MUSIn,..))
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `||` (or) boolean operator. Based on your stacktrace your expression should be something like:

```
expresion= "execution(public com.es.core.message.ResultOrError com.presentation.resource..*.*(com.es.mus.MUSIn,..) || java.util.concurrent.Future com.presentation.resource..*.*(com.es.mus.MUSIn,..)||  scala.concurrent.Future com.presentation.resource..*.*(com.es.mus.MUSIn,..) )"
```

Comment: Yep I just saw that answer in another ticket that I just found.